# How to plot horizontal lines on high and low of the 9.30 candle in 1minute char time frame

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

How to plot horizontal lines for high and low on the candle formed at 9.30 in 1 minute timeframe in pinescript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `hour` and `minute` built-in variables to figure out if it is 09:30.

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © vitruvius

//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

is_930 = (hour == 9) and (minute == 30)

var float hi = na
var float lo = na

hi := is_930 ? high : hi
lo := is_930 ? low : lo

plot(hi, "High", color.green, 1, plot.style_circles)
plot(lo, "Low", color.red, 1, plot.style_circles)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @ vitruvius. It's working perfectly.

Comment: No worries. Then please consider accepting my answer so we know that this question has an answer.

Comment: Thanks for this code it is so simple and straight, I asked similar question to chatgpt4 and it is so stupid and not able to understand. I provided your code and told it to draw it for 920 to 925 candle but it was not able to do it.